# javascript parseInt when value = 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery.grep to clean a string and return only digits.

This is what I have:

```
var TheInputArray = TheInput.slice();
var TheCleanInput = jQuery.grep(TheInputArray, function (a) {
  return parseInt(a, 10);
});
```

I take a string, split it into an array and use the parseInt function to check if it's a number. The problem is that when the value of a is 0, it skips that element. What changes do I need to do to  make this code work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
var TheCleanInput = TheInput.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, `0` in Javascript is falsy.  So you need to be sure your return value is `true`, even for a `0`.

```
var TheInputArray = TheInput.slice();
var TheCleanInput = jQuery.grep(TheInputArray, function (a) {
  return ! isNaN(parseInt(a, 10));
});
```

`parseInt` returns `NaN` (not a number), if it fails to parse the input.  And `isNan()` will return `true` if the argument is `NaN`.  So this should help you detect that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to test whether the element in the array *is* a number, rather than converting it and then building a new array using the converted numbers, you can use the new [`$.isNumeric`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) function (new in 1.7), which tests whether the argument represents a numeric value:

```
var TheCleanInput = jQuery.grep(TheInputArray, function (a) { return $.isNumeric(a); });
```

Note that this does *not* modify the existing array. If the array contains `'5'`, that will remain a string and not be converted to a number. Use `$.map` if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The `parseInt()` function doesn't return a boolean value, it either returns `NaN` for non-numeric values or the converted value for numeric values. If you try to use the result as a boolean you'll find that `NaN` and 0 will both be falsy, while any non-zero number will be equivalent to true.

You can use `isNan()` to check this: `return !isNan(parseInt(a,10));`

Or you can use jQuery's [`$.isNumeric(a)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) function instead (if using jQuery 1.7+).

Or if you just want to remove all non-numeric characters from a string why not use a regex replace:

```
TheInput.replace(/\D/g,"")
```

Even if you specifically want the result as an array I think you're best off using the regex and then converting to an array afterwards because it keeps the code simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the current Version of jQuery (1.7), you can use `jQuery.isNumeric(a)` for that purpose:

```
var TheCleanInput = jQuery.grep(TheInputArray, function (a) { return $.isNumeric(a); });
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
var filterInt = function(value) {
  if (/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/.test(value))
    return Number(value);
  return NaN;
}
```